# How to fetch list of ips using bash script from one particular website say like XYZ.com wesbite

Tags: php, linux, bash, scripting

I have query regarding bash scripting using linux command. I want to create one bash file consisting linux command so that when that scripts gets executed it will result in list of ip address from website https://www.projecthoneypot.org/list_of_ips.php

Comment: Please do not post [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965048/how-to-fetch-list-of-ips-using-batch-file-script-from-one-particular-website-say).

Answer (score 1):

```
lynx -dump https://www.projecthoneypot.org/list_of_ips.php  | awk '/Bad Event [0-9]/{sub("\\[[0-9]+\\]", "", $2) ; print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 wget -q --no-check-certificate -O- "https://www.projecthoneypot.org/list_of_ips.php" | grep -Eo "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])"|uniq>iplist.txt
```

Comment: please explain the each word used in scripts above.

Comment: Please explain the above script or is there any other way to fetch IP?

Comment: @user3167965 this is `grep` with [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). You may also use a programming language to fetch the IP's, like Python, Perl, php, Pascal ....